# Angular - Google places directive isn't being triggered when the input value changes

Tags: angular, typescript, google-places-api, angular2-directives

I'm trying to write a google place directive since all the finished ones doesn't seem to work very well or have a code base that is just horrendous.

So here is my attempt which is clean but it isn't activating when the user types something:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[googlePlace]'
})

export class GoogleplaceDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() placeChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public autocomplete: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.elementRef.nativeElement, {});

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {

      const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();

      this.placeChange.emit(place);
    });
  }
}
```

Which I then use like this:

```
<input formControlName="address" googlePlace (placeChange)="setAddress($event)">
```

But when I type in the input the autocomplete is not triggering, I'm probably missing something simple but I cannot figure out what that could be. Maybe I have to listen to the input manually somehow and then trigger a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As google map events are fired outside angular zone you need to run callback inside angular zone:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
  const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
  this.zone.run(() => this.placeChange.emit(place)); // run inside angular zone
});
```

See also

- [google maps places autocomplete addEventListener doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993843/google-maps-places-autocomplete-addeventlistener-doesnt-work)

Comment: Doesn't work, the problem is that `place_change` doesn't fire at all. So it's like it can't read the input's value somehow.

Comment: It does seem to work ye, seems like the dropdown is being hidden behind some other element on my page which is strange. I guess this one is resolved then :)